# How to check for special characters using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

NET. I have created a regex validator to check for special characters means I donot want any special characters in username. The following is the code

```
Regex objAlphaPattern = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]");
            bool sts = objAlphaPattern.IsMatch(username);
```

If I provide username as    $%^&*asghf  then the validator gives as invalid data format which is the result I want but If I provide a data   s23_@.-^&*()%^$#  then my validator should block the data but my validator allows the data which is wrong

So how to not allow any special characters except a-z A-A 0-9 _ @ .-

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your expression. First you don't have the start string character `^` and end string character `$` at the beginning and end of your expression meaning that it only has to find a match somewhere within your string.

Second, you're only looking for one character currently. To force a match of all the characters you'll need to use `*` Here's what it should be:

```
Regex objAlphaPattern = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]*$");
bool sts = objAlphaPattern.IsMatch(username);
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer Ruport,
               Really your response helped me alot. I did the great mistake then you solved my problem

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo Your post says: `I don not want any special characters in username`. Did you mean you want only numbers and letters and/or any of the following special characters: `_ @ . -`. I'm asking because the accepted response also include these special characters. For example, I tested the above regex and it passes the `Tom@Doe8test.com_Jane-sub` string that contains some special characters mentioned in the pattern, but it fails `Tom@Doe8test.com_Jane-sub#Wen!Fy` string since it contains `#` and `!`.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern checks only if the given string contains any "non-special" character; it does not exclude the unwanted characters. You want to change two things; make it check that the whole string contains only allowed characters, and also make it check for more than one character:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]+$
```

Added `^` before the pattern to make it start matching at the beginning of the string. Also added `+$` after, `+` to ensure that there is at least one character in the string, and `$` to make sure that the string is matched to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to `^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]+$`. Here `^` denotes the beginning of a string, `$` is the end of the string.

Comment: I'm not sure it's considered a special character when it's inside the brackets. I could be wrong on this.