# Regex in android for email,username & mobile number

Tags: android, regex

I want to use regex in my android application to validate some field.

#### User Name :

> `1` Capital Letter[A-Z], `2` digit[0-9], `1` Special Character any and then followed by small character[a-z] and lenth would be `10` character max.

#### Email Address :

> Must contain @google.com in last

#### Mobile :

> Must be +91 and after that 10 digit.

How can I form my regex pattern for all three fields..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regx for emailid:

**^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*([._-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z]*.[A-Za-z]{0,3}?.[A-Za-z]{0,2}$**

accepts values as:

- hdf4.j8k@bfv.djf
- ds.sd@c25v.fdv
- dv_sdv@fvv
- vdf-f@jn.fdv
- jfk@mbf.khb.in

n etc

Regex for Mobile No:

**^[7-9][0-9]{9}$**

works perfect for indian mobile numbers.

Regex for landline No:

**^[0-9]{3,5}-[2-9]{1}[0-9]{5,7}$**

for landline numbers in india with region code

eg: 022-58974658

Comment: Put the regex for Username and mobile number also.

Comment: This regex matches `aaa@%§`, not sure it's a valid email address!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the  regex you require for password, email and more , for instance

> For Username :
>
> ^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$
>
> ^                                   # Start of the line
>
> [a-z0-9_-]                   # Match characters and symbols in the list, a-z, 0-9
>   , underscore , hyphen
>
> {3,15}                           # Length at least 3 characters and maximum length of 15
>
> $                                  # End of the line

at : http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link for Email Validation and you can modify some part of the code for username validation and phone number validation.

[how-to-check-edittexts-text-is-email-address-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119722/how-to-check-edittexts-text-is-email-address-or-not)

Comment: how can i put special character validation ?

Comment: [Validate Special Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279433/how-to-check-for-special-characters-using-regex)

Comment: @user1642834 Please see answer of that question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: No need for a flag, just return true inside the if and false outside.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile :

```
Must be +91 and after that 10 digit.
```

**^[7-9][0-9]{9}$** is useful for only mobile numbers. But for country code we should have to use regex like  **^[+(00)][0-9]{6,14}$** ..

something like

*1)*

```
String phoneNumber = "+919900990000"
if(phoneNumber.matches("^[+(00)][0-9]{6,14}$")){
   //True
```

*2)*

```
  String phoneNumber = "9900990000"
  if(phoneNumber.matches("^[+(00)][0-9]{6,14}$")){
   //False
```

The first is true because it has the country code with it, But the second one is false because it has not any country code attached with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Patterns class for validating factors such as email,mobile no etc.
Here's how:

```
public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches());
}

public static boolean isValidMobile(CharSequence target) {
    return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches());
}
```

Hope it'll help you.